# How can I avoid "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Tags: r

I have a loop running to assign values

```
for (i in 1:4)
t[i]<-print(noquote(paste0("t_",i)))
```

the output of which is

```
[1] t_1
[1] t_2
[1] t_3
[1] t_4
```

Now when I try to run it along with a function

```
    for (i in 1:length(t))
    print(sum(t[i]$total_counts))

 it throws up an error: Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

however, it works fine, if i run it like

```
sum(t_1$total_counts)
[1] 27347116
```

what shall I adjust to make my code running in a loop.

Please suggest.

Comment: `mtcars$cyl[1]` is a valid reference, `mtcars[1]$cyl` is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `t_1` to t`_n` are the names of objects in your environment and that you want to loop over said objects and perform an operation. in which case you need to use `get`:

```
t_1 <- data.frame(x=1:10, y = 11:20)
t <- "t_1"
sum(get(t[1])$x)
#[1] 55
```

As @joran suggests, the better way to do this is to collect all of the `t_n` objects into a list and then operate over the list.

```
t_list <- mget(t)
lapply(t_list, function(df) sum(df$x))
```

Comment: Rather than encourage this somewhat problematic code pattern, you could recommend `mget` as a way to collect all those `t_*` objects into a named list.